# How do I create a Tic Tac Toe board of arbitrary size in Java?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

For my assignment, I have to create a Tic Tac Toe game where the board is of abitrary size... I know how to create a board that is 3X3, but I don't know where to start here. My instructor wants us to create the board inside a class TicTacToe using

```
public TicTacToe(int edgesize) {
}
```

so when i create my abitrary sized board, should I start with this?

```
public TicTacToe(int edgesize){
  int [][] board = new int[edgesize] [edgesize]
}
```

Comment: `int [][] board = new int[edgesize][edgesize]`

Comment: Can you write a standard 3x3 board class?  Sometimes it is helpful to start with the specific case and then go back and generalize it.

Comment: Read about variable scope and class members

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
public TicTacToe(int edgesize){
   int [][] board = new int[edgesize] [edgesize]
}
```

`board` variable will be local to the constructor itself. Which means it won't be available outside the constructor.

Make `board` an instance level variable, and use the constructor to instantiate the array for it, so that it will be available to all the instance methods in your `TicTacToe` class:

```
public class TicTacToe {
    private int[][] board;

    public TicTacTo(int size) {
        this.board = new int[size][size];
        //initialize the board
    }

    //write methods to do stuffs with the board
```

Answer (score 0):

Your board declaration should be outside the constructor, i.e. it should be an *instance variable*, it should be the property of your class so that you can access/manipulate it easily with getters/setters. You are declaring it as a *local variable* currently, and it's a wrong methodology.

```
public class TicTacToe
{
   int[][] board;

   public TicTacToe(int edgesize)
   {
     this.board = new int[edgesize][edgesize];
   }

   //Getter and setter for your "board".

   public int[][] getBoard()
   { return board; }
   public void setBoard(int[][] board)
   { this.board = board; }

   //Some other methods for iterating your "board" maybe, etc.
}
```

Comment: I would not add a setBoard() method until you have a requirement for it.  Also, even though you can get it from board.length, I'd also store edgesize in an instance variable.  Cause you will need it later for loops, checking for a winner, etc...

Comment: @user949300 you are definitely right, i just tried to show the importance of global scope for this situation to the OP.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a global variable.

Comment: @BheshGurung it is a global variable, but i think you mean the term "instance variable" is better. thank you, see my edit.